# ExtJs check if form values has changed

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

is there a possibility to check if form values has changed in ExtJs?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
myForm.getForm().items.each(function(field){field.on('change',function(f,n,o){alert('detected! '+f.label+' value changed from '+o+' to '+n);});});
```

In the above snippet, what you are basically doing is -

- Iterate over all fields in the form (`myForm.getForm().items.each()`)
- For each field, add a change listener. (`field.on(...)`)
- When a field's value is changed, the listener will be invoked with the field info and old and new value.
- In the listener, change the alert with the appropriate logic.

Comment: I wan't to add that instead of using `myForm.getForm().items` it's probably better to use `myForm.getForm().getFields()` in ExtJS4.